# How can I display a list of items but disable mutli select in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, select

I'm having trouble finding an example on how to present a list of items from select, but without enabling multi select (which I don't want).

My code:

```
<select id="documentList" class="selectAlternateEvens" style="width: 85%; height: 300px;"
ng-options="a.key as a.value for a in documentList" multiple ng-model="selectedDocument">
</select>
```

I would like to have documentList presented as a... listbox, but only be able to select 1 document at a time (selectedDocument would no longer be an array I'd imagine).  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'multiple' attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'multiple' attribute is what enables multiple selection. Remove it.

If you just want to show a list instead of a dropdown, use the 'size' attribute.

```
<select id="documentList" class="selectAlternateEvens" style="width: 85%; height: 300px;"
ng-options="a.key as a.value for a in documentList" size="4" ng-model="selectedDocument">
</select>
```

Comment: The size attribute is what I was looking for, thanks!